# org.springframework.ui.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean Template not found

Tags: spring, freemarker

Now I am trying to load the FreeMarker from the dependency jar and my config file is :

```
<bean id="freemarkerConfiguration" class="org.springframework.ui.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean">
        <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="classpath*:/mailer_templates" />
</bean>
```

But I got this error :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Template "test.ftl" not found.
        at freemarker.template.Configuration.getTemplate(Configuration.java:742)
        at freemarker.template.Configuration.getTemplate(Configuration.java:681)
```

I can`t move the template files from dependency jar to the current project dir.Is there any solutions ?

thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know Spring's FreeMarker `TemplateLoader`-s, but why `classpath*:` instead of `classpath`? You need exactly one template, not a set of them. Maybe that leads to  your problem too.

Comment: hi @ddekany, because the templates are in the denpendency jar file and I can`t move it out. many projects depend on it ):

Comment: I'm not talking about `classpath:`, I'm talking about the `*` there. I suppose you shouldn't use it there.

Comment: If I use classpath without * it will not load the templates in the jar file

Comment: As far as I know `classpath*:` is for finding *all* occurrences of a resource with the same name, as opposed to just one. `classpath:` should find the resource anywhere too, but only one of them.